# Is there a way to skip init method in viewmodel?

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, viewmodel

Is there a way to **not** execute the init method when calling the viewmodel into the fragment?

This is how my fragment looks:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class WelcomeFragment : BaseFragment(R.layout.fragment_welcome) {

    //Here I call the viewmodel
    private val notificationViewModel: NotificationViewModel by viewModels()
```

This is the viewmodel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class NotificationViewModel @Inject constructor(
    screenAnalytics: SegmentScreenAnalytics,
) : BaseViewModel() {

    //I want to skip this method
    init {
        screenAnalytics.screenNotifications()
    }
```

EDIT: Sorry I didn't give the whole context before.

I call that viewmodel from another fragment too, and that fragment does need the code inside init to execute when the fragment is launched. What I would like excatly is to execute the init only when one of those fragments calls the viewmodel

Thanks a lot

Comment: Move that code out of the `init` method?

Comment: The `init` function will be called when a class is instantiated, remove any code from this block you don't want to execute.  The `by viewmodels()` delegate function is actually a sub-class of `Lazy<T>` so your viewmodel won't be instantiated until its called for the first time, which is different to what you currently think.

Comment: Sorry I didn't give the whole context before.

I call that viewmodel from another fragment too, and that fragment does need the code inside init to execute when the fragment is launched. What I would like excatly is to execute the init only when one of those fragments calls the viewmodel

Answer (score 1):

You could try to send a bool parameter via `SavedStateHandle` to the viewmodel, then, inside the ini, check the bool state and execute `screenAnalytics.screenNotifications()` based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove init block !!!

Comment: I call that viewmodel from another fragment as well, and I want that init to be executed when the other fragment uses the viewmodel. Sorry, I didn't write the whole context

Comment: Ok , you can send boolean parameters using bundle , and if this parameters was true call this function in init block  , else  nothing.

 its better to  call your function from onCreate method in fragment  , if its possible in your case;